# How to get the result of read_line() as a String in Rust?

Tags: rust, tostring

I'm trying to get a `String` from standard input:

```
use std::io;

fn ask_nick() -> String {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer: String = String::new();

    let nickname: String = reader.read_line(&mut buffer).ok()
        .expect("ERRMSG").to_string();

        println!("OK: Hello {}!", &nickname);
        return nickname;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let nickname: String = ask_nick();
    println!("{}", nickname);
}
```

But conversion from `usize` to `String` seems to change contents to it's length:

```
          INPUT:= John
EXPECTED OUTPUT:= OK: Hello John!
                  John
         OUTPUT:= OK: Hello 5!
                  5

          INPUT:= Doe
EXPECTED OUTPUT:= OK: Hello Doe!
                  Doe
         OUTPUT:= OK: Hello 4!
                  4
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you expect the program to output?

Comment: @TimDiekmann   I've edited the question contents. How should I convert reader.read_line(&mut buffer) which is a usize, into a String, without changing the contents of it into the length of it's contents?

Comment: The best way to convert a `usize` to a `String` is via `to_string`, exactly as you are doing. What is your *real* question?

Comment: @Shepmaster The issue is a confusion over how `read_line` works. OP is expecting the function to return the line, but it actually returns the number of bytes read and mutates the provided buffer.

Comment: Arrived here after searching for a rust equivalent of C# ReadLine. What should have been a 2 minute task isn't. I can't understand why Rust is so popular in SO surveys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line), and you can see that `read_line` *mutates* the contents of its parameter (in your case, the empty string bound at `buffer`), putting the value read into it, and returns *the length read*. But you're unwrapping that result and converting that length to a string.

Instead, your function should look like:

```
fn ask_nick() -> String {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer: String = String::new();

    reader.read_line(&mut buffer)
        .ok()
        .expect("ERRMSG");

    println!("OK: Hello {}!", buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Or, even more idiomatically, not panicking when invalid input is provided:

```
fn ask_nick() -> Result<String> {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer: String = String::new();

    match reader.read_line(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(buffer),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

In this variant, the caller is the one that decides how to handle errors.

Comment: Apart from the incorrect usage of the `nickname` variable after its been removed (in your first snippet), this is correct. You also don't need to pass them by reference to the `println` macro as it'll not take ownership anyway.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead good catch! i actually mentally ignored that line by accident.

Comment: I think you could replace that last match with `reader.read_line(&mut buffer).map(|_| buffer)`, if you wanted to be really terse :) Unless there's some weirdness with the closure move semantics that I've not accounted for, that is!