# How to cast string to integer in RUST

Tags: rust

How to cast string to integer from io::read_line in RUST?

```
let mut val: String = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut val).expect("Error");
```

Comment: Hello, this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305052/how-to-get-the-result-of-read-line-as-a-string-in-rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your thing:

```
let parsed_int: i32 = val.parse().expect("Couldn't parse!");
```